# Run cockpit cms on dokku

Tags: php, heroku, dokku

I'm trying to run [cockpit cms](https://github.com/agentejo/cockpit) which comes with a dockerfile on a dokku server. The deploy is OK however I can't accces the site. I get a 403 in the browser and in the logs it says:

```
AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

I assume I need to set `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` somewhere?!?

Where do I set this and to which path do I set it?

Can I set this as an ENV? Is it `/home/dokku/appname`?

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: I'm new to both dokku and cockpit cms.

Comment: Have you fixed it ? I run into the same issue with the same logs

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and noticed that `var/www/html` folder was empty after entering in my dokku apps container. Copying files fixed 403 errors but create an issue on install to create database files in `storage`folder.
So, i just added these lines in `Dockerfile` :

```
...

# Dokku fix
COPY . /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage

VOLUME /var/www/html

...
```